# Can I have someone submit my transaction to the network, so I don't have to pay the gas fee (in ether)?

Tags: transactions, ether, erc-20

My account is a new account with 0 ether. I just received 100 of ERC20 tokens. I would like to send these 100 tokens to the other account. However, since this account does not have any ether in it, so it cannot submit any transaction to the network.

I wonder, is it possible to have someone (3rd party account) submit my transaction transferring 100 tokens from this account to the other one. I don't want to transfer any ether to this account to make it possible to merely submit 1 transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not something that can be done on the network today, but there are proposals to allow similar things to occur:

- [ERC865: Pay transfers in tokens instead of gas, in one transaction](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/865)
- [EIP1035: Transaction execution batching and delegation](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/1035)

One thing you may be able to try today is submit a transaction with a gas cost of zero, and hope some miner picks it up, but it may take a very long time to confirm...

Answer (score 2):

As Shawn Tabrizi answer, we cannot do it without gas fee. For 3rd party account I can put an addition as below.

> I wonder, is it possible to have someone (3rd party account) submit my
>   transaction transferring 100 tokens from this account to the other
>   one. I don't want to transfer any ether to this account to make it
>   possible to merely submit 1 transaction.

Actually, you can approve other people to transfer your ERC20 token by calling `function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);` but calling `approve()` also need pay some gas fee.